# Where to place the RSS button?

Tags: website-design, buttons

I am making a website and am confused as I don't know where to place the RSS button.
Considering this is my website: [My Website](https://blog.utkarshverma.me)

Should I place the RSS button only on post pages? Or should I place it throughout the website?
I'd like to clarify that I know where to place the RSS button in terms of layout(planning to place it on the top right corner), I'm asking where is it deemed useful and *not annoying*?

Comment: do you have a footer with other whole-site-relevant links? that's where i usually see rss links...

Comment: I don't have a footer. That's why I'm placing it on the top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that through out the website, because as user perspective if you add that on post pages, then it will not friendly for a user because every time they need to navigate a post page to see that link.

From my perspective, it's best practice to make things easy, rather than difficult to navigate.